# Having an object required error in Access. Every other situation here is far too complex

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I'm a new access programmer and I've been tasked with taking the old school index card / excel spreadsheet inventory system at work (an internship) and making an access database (because interns always get the "fun" jobs) Anyway, I say that other situations here are too complex because mine is really simple. My function follows as thus:

```
Public Function PartNumMod()
On Error GoTo Part_Number_Macro_Err
    DoCmd.Requery "Subform1"
    Forms!Subform1.SourceObject = Queries![Part Number Query]
Part_Number_Macro_Exit:
    Exit Function
Part_Number_Macro_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Part_Number_Macro_Exit
End Function
```

This function is called from a button on a form called Search form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT Inventory.[PART NUMBER], Inventory.DESCRIPTION, Inventory.Location, Inventory.[B#9 Of], Inventory.[B#11 FM], Inventory.[B#14 DA], Inventory.[B#15 TL], Inventory.[B#16 WH], Inventory.[B#17 MH], Inventory.[B#22 TN], Inventory.[B#24], Inventory.QTY
FROM Inventory
WHERE (((Inventory.[PART NUMBER]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search Form]![WhatPart] & "*"));
```

Here is part number query as requested.

Comment: Where does the error occur? why do you first requery and then change the sourceObject - the other way around would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Forgot one other thing. The set up on search form is that there are three text boxes with buttons to search by part number, keyword, and ROP value. The partnumber search, (the code posted above) works, and pops up the error, the keyword function which is exactly the same except the names of things are different, doesn't do anything except pop the error up. Thanks.

Comment: @luk2302 I swapped them (I honestly had thought about that yesterday, but order seemed like it would work anyway) With the lines swapped now part number is not getting to the requery, so the issue has to be in
'Forms!Subform1.SourceObject = Queries![Part Number Query]'

Comment: How about posting the Query `Part Number Query`. I am sure a simple requery of the recordsource of the form is all you need.

Comment: @luk2302 Queries should be part of the path to the query isnt it? Like I said totally new to access. Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Are you trying to specify another query or another form? `SourceObject` is for `Forms`, `RecordSource` is for `Queries`! As fas as I can see you try to set SourceObject = Query

Comment: Right now I have the sourceobject of subform1 set to the Part Number Query. Tried setting it to 
    Query.[Part Number Query]

Comment: Also, a simple requery can do what I need it to do, but I want to use the same subform to display the results from multiple different queries depending on what button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I wasn't referencing things correctly.  Following is my code, all prettied up and ready to see daylight.

```
'Tests to make sure that the subform isnt already loaded with the query
If Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject <> "Query.Part Number Query" Then
   'In theory, this should change the source of the subform to display the part number query
    Forms![Search Form]!Subform1.SourceObject = "Query.Part Number Query"
End If 

'Runs the requery on subform to refresh
DoCmd.Requery "Subform1"
```

So yeah. Resolution. Lets pray the boss likes it.

Thanks guys,

Santh